# How can one construct a directed expander graph with varying degree distributions (not d-regular)?

Tags: spectral-graph-theory, directed-graphs

Most of the results on expanders assume a d-regular undirected graph - eg, exponentially fast mixing, etc. Is it possible to construct expanders that are directed and not d-regular?

Comment: What results? This is unclear... (And your title question is different.)

Comment: Sorry, should have made it clear that I have two questions about expanders. My real question is whether we can construct directed, varying degree expander graphs?